# How Can I Make Excel Files Open In The OneDrive Web Version?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

I no longer have Excel installed and only have the OneDrive option available to me.

If I Right-Click on an xlsx file there is the option "View online" which opens a web browser and opens the file in onedrive.live.com in edit mode.

I can't find a registry entry for it and a bat file with `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /viewonline "%1"` just opens another instance of Windows Explorer.

How can I achieve this functionality by double clicking on the file?

Comment: The [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-office-for-the-web-in-onedrive-dc62cfd4-120f-4dc8-b3a6-7aec6c26b55d) says "When you can see the document on OneDrive, click it. It opens in an Microsoft 365 for the web program". If simple-click doesn't work, try double-click.

Comment: @harrymc, the question is about a local XLSX file, not in OneDrive online.

Comment: @YisroelTech: In that case we need more details from the poster.

Comment: How about copying the file to your onedrive

Comment: The file is already on OneDrive (synced/backup by the OneDrive desktop app) else it would not have the View online option in the Windows Context menu. But he wants to be able to double-click the file to open in the online viewer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be possible. (There is quite a bit of people online looking for something like it but with no positive results, see for example https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2353207-onedrive-view-online-default-action-on-double-click-hack and https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/nmdszk/set_default_to_open_office_documents_through_the/)

You can try voting for this OneDrive Feedback entry https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/720191e3-4fe6-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008